# Is there a way to query multiple tables at the same time in Sails?

Tags: angularjs, sails.js, waterline, sails-postgresql

I've been tasked with adding an Angular Typeahead search field to a site and the data needs to come from multiple tables. It needs to be a "search all the things" kind of query which looks for people, servers, and applications in one spot.

I was thinking the best way to do this would be to have a single API endpoint in Sails which could pull from 3 tables on the same DB and send the results, but I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in [bluebird library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html), specifically [Promise.all()](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html). To handle the results, use [.spread()](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html). Example controller code (modify to suit your case):

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = {

    searchForStuff: function(req, res) {
        var params = req.allParams();
        // Replace the 'find' criteria with whatever suitable for your case
        var requests = [
            Person.find({name: params.searchString}),
            Server.find({name: params.searchString}),
            Application.find({name: params.searchString})
        ];
        Promise.all(requests)
        .spread(function(people, servers, applications) {
            return res.json({
                people: people,
                servers: servers,
                applications: applications
            })
        })
    }

}
```